# How to make nested JSON response with Array from a Stored procedure

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa

I have a data set that is generated from a Stored procedure

```
+------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| Line |Status  | Consent             | tid        |
+------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 1001 | 1      | Yes                 | 1054       |
| 1002 | 1      | yes                 | 1055       |
| 1003 | 1      | Yes                 | 3045       |
| 1004 | 1      | No                  | 3046       |
| 1005 | 0      | No                  | 1023       |
| 1006 | 0      | Yes                 | 1024       |
| 1007 | 1      | No                  | 1025       |
+------+--------+---------------------+------------+
```

I want to be able to generate a `JSON` like from the data I get from the stored procedure

```
{
    "totalMembers": 9,
    "questionaryinfo": [
        {
            "line": "1001",
            "status": "1",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "tid": "1054",
            "adultquestionary":"Yes"
        },
        {
            "line": "1002",
            "status": "1",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "tid": "1055",
            "adultquestionary":"Yes"
        },
        {
            "line": "1003",
            "status": "1",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "tid": "3035",
            "adultquestionary":"Yes"
        },
}
```

I have tried using hash maps

public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> retrieveLineListing(String Case){

```
    StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("get_listing", "ListingModel");
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("Case", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    query.setParameter("Case", Case);
    query.execute();

    List list = query.getResultList();

    Map<String, Object> parent = new HashMap<>();
    parent.put("totalMembers", 9);

    parent.put("questionaryinfo", new HashMap<String, Object>());
  parent.put("questionaryinfo", new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>());
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listings = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>) parent.get("questionaryinfo");
if (list != null) {
    list.forEach(d -> {
        HashMap<String,Object> entry = new HashMap<>();

        entry.put("adultquestionary","Yes");
        entry.put("consent", list.get(1));
        listings.add(entry);
    });
}
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(parent);
}
```

UPDATE 1

After amending to how @Rahul advised me to do,

my JSON looks like

```
{
    "totalMembers": 9,
    "questionaryinfo": [
      "consent"{
        {
            "line": "1001",
            "status": "1",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "tid": "1054",
          
        },
        "adultquestionary":"Yes"
      }
      "consent"{
        {
            "line": "1002",
            "status": "1",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "tid": "1055",
        },
        "adultquestionary":"Yes"
      },
      "consent"{
        {
            "line": "1003",
            "status": "1",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "tid": "3035",
        },
        "adultquestionary":"Yes"
      },
      ]
    }
```

How can I set up my method to generate the nested JSON above and get the Line, Status, consent and tid values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use **DTO models** for your *requests* and *responses* as a better practice in your Resource/Controller layer. You will still need to populate the model correctly with the stored procedure response, but that should not be a challenge from what I can see in your post.

The real benefits of encapsulating the format of your response into a single model are *flexibility*, *extensibility* and the *variety of responses* you API may return.

For you to retrieve the payload defined above, it must be as simple as this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/stackoverflow")
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> read() {
        List<Consent> result = mockStoreProcedureResult();
        ResponseDTO response = ResponseDTO.builder()
                .totalMembers(result.size())
                .questionaryInfo(result)
                .build();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }

}
```

In which `ResponseDTO` model encapsulates the desired shape of your response. You will see that I also created a `Consent` model that reflects your initial proposal.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class ResponseDTO {
    private Integer totalMembers;
    private List<Consent> questionaryInfo;
}


@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class Consent {
     private String line;
     private String status;
     private String consent;
     private String tid;
     private String adultQuestionary;
}
```

When I ran the demo app and make a request, I get a similar response to what you are looking for. If I wanted to alter the format of the objects inside `questionaryInfo`, is just as simple as editing the model being used for that.

```
curl -X GET --location "http://localhost:8080/v1/stackoverflow" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json"

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 29 Jun 2021 18:35:11 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "totalMembers": 3,
  "questionaryInfo": [
    {
      "line": "1001",
      "status": "1",
      "consent": "Yes",
      "tid": "1054",
      "adultQuestionary": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "line": "1002",
      "status": "1",
      "consent": "Yes",
      "tid": "1055",
      "adultQuestionary": "Yes"
    },
    {
      "line": "1003",
      "status": "1",
      "consent": "Yes",
      "tid": "3055",
      "adultQuestionary": "Yes"
    }
  ]
}
```

Hope you find this useful, cheers.

**Edit:** Answering to your question @arriff, how do you inject values to your response model?

You could easily iterate over the list you get back from your stored procedure and map each entry into your model. For that a constructor must be defined in you model that can receive the expected parameters.

```
public List<Consent> getConsentAnswers() {
    return dbStoreProcedureResult().stream()
            .map(dbo -> new Consent(dbo, "Yes", "Yes"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Here is the additional custom constructor defined for `Consent` model.

```
public Consent(@NonNull DBConsent dbo,
               @NonNull String consent,
               @NonNull String adultQuestionary) {
     this.line = dbo.getLine();
     this.tid = dbo.getTid();
     this.status = dbo.getStatus();
     this.consent = consent;
     this.adultQuestionary = adultQuestionary;
}
```

Comment: Hi @nev3rmore, thank you for your response but there are some fields am injecting manually using `entry.put("adultquestionary","Yes");` which dont come from the Stored procedure, how will add those to the response?

Comment: Hey @arriff, added an EDIT section to the post answering your question.

Comment: Hi @nev3rmore, I think am more confused, are you using hashmaps anywhere in you implementation?

Comment: No, and you don't need either. In your example, I am assuming I will receive a list of elements from my stored procedure call, i.e., `List list = query.getResultList();`, then I will iterate over this list to create models for my response. Remember, the way you structure your models is how they will look like in the response representation. 

If you do it like that, you don't need to do any funky things like `ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listings = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>) ...` which are hard to read.

Comment: Yes `List list = query.getResultList();` will return a list of  elements, I have never used DTO i will have to go and read about them, Some few  questions as I am still completely lost. My list  `List list = query.getResultList();` will return a list of  elements, then I do a `return list;` Then I create a model correctly with the stored procedure response on the controller,? I have added how my controler looks like currently. Is this similar `mockStoreProcedureResult();`to my call for the stored procedure?

Comment: Yes, with each element of your list you will create a piece of the response model. Remember, your DTO model can have any constructor definition you require to handle your use case, e.g, `public Consent(Map<String,Object> element) { ... }`. A brief description of DTO, it stands for Data Transfer Object, is just a POJO that you move along the domains of you application.

Comment: where should I define this `getConsentAnswers` inside the consent class? And which method is this `dbStoreProcedureResult` and what should it do? and what bit does this do `@NonNull DBConsent dbo,` have been able to pull the data successfully using the DTO, inject values to my response model is the remaining challenge

Comment: You don't have to take the example by hearth. With `dbStoreProcedureResult()`I was trying to emulate the result of your store procedure, basically this line `query.getResultList()`, the rest of the methods, well those you can place them wherever you seem more appropriate to your code base. The `@NonNull DBConsent dbo` is a model I created to emulate what I may get back from a StoredProcedure call, not necessarily true, it could be a Map. TL;DR; Those were just examples to provide visualization on how to achieve your expected Response.

Answer (score 1):

Not tried, but this should run:

```
parent.put("questionaryinfo", new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>());
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listings = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>) parent.get("questionaryinfo");
if (list != null) {
    list.forEach(d -> {
        HashMap<String,Object> entry = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        
        entry.put("adultquestionary","Yes");
        entry.put("consent", list.get(0));
        listings.add(entry);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Rahul, almost there but it generates the  data as `{
    "totalMembers": 9,
    "questionaryinfo": [
        "consent"{
            "line": "1001",
            "status": "1",
            "consent": "Yes",
            "tid": "1054",
        },
 "adultquestionary":"Yes"
}`