# Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to .model.ISOVER at java.util.ArrayList.forEach

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Am trying to get data from 3 tables and every time I end up getting an error

> Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to .model.ISECO at
> java.util.ArrayList.forEach

This are my entities

```
@Entity
public class IS01 {
    private String IEA;
    private String INUM;
    private String ILINE;
    private String I0103;

@Entity
public class ISOVER {
    private String IEA;
    private String ILINE;
    private String INUM;
    private String IRESULT;
    private String ICON;
    private String IBCON;
    private String CASE;
    private String RPTID

@Entity
public class POSTCO {
    private String CEA;
    private String CNUM;
    private String CLINE;
    private String PSCONTACT;
```

And this is my Repository

```
public interface LineSummary extends CrudRepository<ISOVER , String> {

    @Query("select c.ILINE , c.IRESULT,e.PSCONTACT, \n" +
            "c.ICON,c.IBCON, c.RPTID, c.CASE, d.i0103 as age\n" +
            "FROM ISOVER c \n" +
            "inner join IS01 d \n" +
            "on c.IEA = d.IEA and c.INUM = d.INUM and c.ILINE = d.ILINE\n" +
            "inner join POSTCO e on d.IEA = e.CEA and d.INUM = e.CNUM and d.ILINE = e.CLINE\n" +
            "where c.CASE like %?1%")
     Iterable<ISOVER> findEntriesByUserId(@Param("Case") String Case);
```

And this is my service

```
public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> retrieveLineListingSQL(String Case){

    Iterable <ISOVER > stud = lineSummary.findEntriesByUserId(Case);


    Map<String, Object> parents = new HashMap<>();
    parents.put("totalMembers", 9);

    parents.put("questionaryinfo", new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>());
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> listings = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>) parents.get("questionaryinfo");
    if (stud != null) {
        stud.forEach(d -> {
            HashMap<String,Object> entry = new HashMap<>();

            entry.put("adultquestionary","Yes");
            entry.put("caseNumber", d.getCASE());
            listings.add(entry);
        });
    }


    parents.put("DMStatus", "No review");
    parents.put("ages",  new HashMap<String, Object>());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(parents);
}
```

How can I return the results from the query and map them accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is your culprit:

```
if (stud != null) {
    stud.forEach(d -> {
        HashMap<String, Object> entry = new HashMap<>(); // < -- here

        entry.put("adultquestionary","Yes");
        entry.put("caseNumber", d.getCASE());
        listings.add(entry);
    });
}
```

Have your tried using `*.model.ISECO` instead of `java.lang.Object`? Does that work, any particular limitation?

Additionally, you could refactor you code to something way more simple, if you follow the same explanation provided in here: [How to make nested JSON response with Array from a Stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68181222/how-to-make-nested-json-response-with-array-from-a-stored-procedure)

1. Create a response model that outputs the format you expect as response.
2. There is no need for you to do all that collections handling one-by-one. The representation of an object in JSON is a MAP, basically let the
   Jackson JSON library do all that work for you.